# Where can I find real world salt and pepper noise image?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for real world salt and pepper or gaussian noise images. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following image data sets with the requested distortions can be found with the following links:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Discrete+Tone+Image+Dataset#
[http://signal.ece.utexas.edu/~bevans/synthetic/](http://signal.ece.utexas.edu/%7Ebevans/synthetic/)

However, they are synthetic data sets and, for the second link, you will need to contact some one for the password.

I did find one with natural images that had the noise synthetically introduced.

https://www.kaggle.com/tarunpathak/natural-images-with-synthetic-noise